# Adding another language files if I already have `vim-polyglot`

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-polyglot

Do I need to add other language files for syntax etc.. if I already have [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) which have pretty much every language.

If I install another language package will they conflict with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's ftplugin (also syntax etc.) uses `:runtime!` to load 2nd level plugins which means all found files will be sourced. Also normally ftplugin plugins include the standard guard at the top of file

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if (exists("b:did_ftplugin"))
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

For this reason, there should not be any kind of "simple conflict", but you'll be dependent on the load-order instead. As the load-order itself depends on (reverse) lexicographical order, it doesn't seem any practical.

So you probably have to deal with package own setup, such as `let g:polyglot_disabled = ['foobar']`, as suggested in polyglot's README.

Comment: Not *all* ftplugins do this; when you want to extend an ftplugin, you omit the guard (eg, none of my .vim/after/ftplugin files have it).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well, I write "normally", not "always". Of course, "after"-plugins, or ".foo.bar.baz"-plugins are supposed to extend existing functionality, and so they are exceptions under this topic.